# How to arrange values alphabetically in php in their own cloumn

Tags: php

I have arranged values alphabetically according to their starting alphabet 
    section, values starting with A to be under the A column header, and 
    companies starting with B to be under the B header...or if i have no value 
    with the value of B then B be skipped. And to show just 5 values... But 
    problem is that **values seprating from their column headers and i wants to show then in their own cloumn header**...here is my 
    code.

```
  <?php
    $sql = "select company_name from companies ORDER BY company_name ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $company = $data['company_name'];
       creatCompanyList($company, $letter,$count);
     }
   $count = 0;  
   $letter = '';
    //echo $count;
  function creatCompanyList($company, &$letter, &$count){
    // echo $count;
    if($letter !== $company[0]) {
       if($count >0) { 
          endCompanyList();
          $count = 0;
      }
      $letter = $company[0];
      startCompanyList($letter, $count);
    }
   if($letter == $company[0] && $count <= 4) addCompanyList($company);
   if($count==4) endCompanyList();
     $count++;
  }
  function startCompanyList($letter, &$count){
  ?>
  <li class="loop-entry">
    <div class="col"> <span><?php echo $letter?></span>
      <div class="list-col">
  <?php
   }
  function endCompanyList(){
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  </li>         
  <?php
  }
 function addCompanyList($company){
 ?>
 <a href="#"><?php echo $company?></a>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

This is screen shot of webpage and i wants the values of E in E column header

[image: this is shot of webpage, and i wants the column header dont repeat and values of E show in E column header]

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yes i wants that the values of one column header dont repeat again and show one after another

Comment: Did you try to compare them saving the header values in a Session?

Comment: yes! but still same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code considers lowercase and uppercase of a letter not the same. Fixed that by including `strtolower()` condition in your `if statements`.

Also added `strtoupper()` for your header letter so it always appears uppercase in case lowercase letter is passed as header.

**Updated Code:**

```
  <?php

    $sql = "select company_name from companies ORDER BY company_name ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $company = $data['company_name'];
       creatCompanyList($company, $letter,$count);
     }
   $count = 0;  
   $letter = '';
    //echo $count;
  function creatCompanyList($company, &$letter, &$count){
    // echo $count;
    if(strtolower($letter) !== strtolower($company[0])) {
       if($count >0) { 
          endCompanyList();
          $count = 0;
      }
      $letter = $company[0];
      startCompanyList($letter, $count);
    }
   if(strtolower( $letter ) == strtolower( $company[0] ) && $count <= 4) addCompanyList($company);
   if($count==4) endCompanyList();
     $count++;
  }
  function startCompanyList($letter, &$count){
  ?>
  <li class="loop-entry">
    <div class="col"> <span><?php echo strtoupper( $letter )?></span>
      <div class="list-col">
  <?php
   }
  function endCompanyList(){
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  </li>         
  <?php
  }
 function addCompanyList($company){
 ?>
 <a href="#"><?php echo $company?></a>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```